# Link height is greater than parent h2 if body or h2 have a line-height

Tags: height, css

[Reduced test case here.](http://dabblet.com/gist/3128786)

I'm trying to understand why this occurs.

If I have an `<a>` within an `<h2>` and set a line height on either the `<body>` or `<h2>` the link height is greater than the `<h2>`.

[Update to clarify] The issue is that .title a has a computed height of 58px, whereas its parent h2.title has a computed height of 50px. I expected them both to have the same computed height. [/update]

I've given them both bottom borders to better illustrate the problem.

[Update 2] I've read over the [line-height spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-line-height) to try and understand this.

From my reading of the spec it seems like an inline element `a` within a block-level element `h2` ought to inherit the parent line-height. I've edited my example [here](http://dabblet.com/gist/3143850) with a larger line-height on the `h2`. Giving the `a` a display of inline-block obviously makes it fit, but it still doesn't line through as well as removing line-height altogether (thus using browser default line-height of 1.2).

This is probably not a *problem* as such, I'd just like to understand the behavior.

[Update 3] I've realised that if I change the `line-height` of the `a` to be greater than the `h2` the overall height of the `h2` box (pink in example above) *does* increase, so the `a` is inheriting the `line-height` from the `h2`. The confusing thing is that the link height (clickable area) and border-bottom position don't change, whereas the border-bottom on the `h2` moves with the line-height.

Comment: what you are trying to say... i cnt understand the prob..

Comment: Dunno for sure what you mean by "link height"

Comment: Did you mean `font-size: 3rem;` to be valid as `font-size: 3em;` or some other measure as `rem` is invalid.

Comment: Surely if I've set a universal line-height on the `<body>` this should also apply to the `<a>`? Basically I'm not getting the behavior I expected and I'm trying to understand why.

Comment: @Mike Fulton: link height means `.title a` has a computed height of `58px`. The height of its parent, `h2.title` is `50px`

Comment: `rem` isn't invalid, it's a CSS3 unit. It mean 'root em' and refers to the `<body>` font-size. In production code you would obviously have a fallback `font-size` in px.

Comment: @Ana: Yes, that's what I meant. I'll add that bit of detail to my question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see your problem. In the link you provide there is absolutely nothing strange. You have a link in a h2. So the font-size of the link gets the font-size of h2. But the a is nowhere bigger than the h2.

Comment: See my update above for clarification on what I think the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't an issue?

However add `display:block;` to your anchor and it will act more like you expect

Comment: I tried this before to see what effect it had. It obviously gets a result closer to that expected; but it's still a few pixels out.

Comment: If you add simply `display:block;` to `<a>` in your code, `<h2> border` and `<a> border` never overlap.  _"<h2> heights"_ = _"<a> border-width x2"_ + _"<a> height"_

Answer (score 0):

you have a h2 containing a link.

the h2 and the link have a line height of 1 (as inherited) but the link has a explicit font size of 3em.

that means, the font size is bigger as the container, which might lead to different results in different browsers.

in Firefox (version 13) the result is, that you have an overflow to the top and the bottom of the parent container (h2).

Comment: The `<h2>` has a `font-size` of 3rem and a `line-height` of 1 (as inherited). Should the `<a>`, as a child of the `<h2>`, not inherit both the `line-height` and `font-size`? I have also tried explicitly setting a `line-height` on the `<a>` and changing its `font-size` to 3rem, neither of which had any effect. Also, removing the `line-height` altogether makes them line up fine as expected.

Comment: Yes, but the problem is, that "line-height: 1;" equals 1 * font-size of the browser and "font-size: 3em;" equals 3 * font-size of the browser, which means the font-size is 3 times bigger than the line-height

Comment: No, as far as I know, that's not how line-height inheritance works. The declaration `line-height:1;` is what's inherited, rather than the result of `line-height:1;` applied to the body `font-size`. So, on the `h2`, line-height equals 1 × 3.3em which equals 48px. If I change the body line-height declaration to 1.5 the `h2` line-height changes to 72px.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried removing the margins of the `<H3>` ? it has default margin to 0.5em in most browsers.

If this was the problem you can read about [Reset CSS](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/).

**Edit:**
you have 2 types of containers, a floted block element  with strict fixed height;
and a inline  witch has auto hate .. and default margins and spacings  (imagin a link as part of a paragraph...).

To get the expected result you can add  `display:inline-block` on the `<a>`.
So they both will be treated as boxes with fixed height.

http://dabblet.com/gist/5219955